# get the all the id's from a class when the image is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few uploaded images in one div and I want to move them to another div and update the database table. For that I need the id's of the images selected and the name of the div where I want to move.

I have the id of the selected image using the check box but I am not sure how can I get all id's in the end .

```
function MoveImages(){
   for ( var i = 0; i < $(".ct input[type=checkbox]:checked").length; i++) {
        var element = $(".ct input[type=checkbox]:checked")[i];
        var parent = element.parentNode;
        var id = parent.getAttribute('id');     
    }
 }
```

how can I get all the id's in the end ?
This is how my class looks like.

```
<div class="ct" id="559429bc0d559162552c9728">
       <input type="checkbox" class="remove">
      <img src="/image?id=c9728" data-src="random.JPG"  id="previewImagec9728">
</div>
```

the move function should return all the id's.

Answer (score 1):

With a bit of JQuery's $.each, substring, and JS array methods, you can grab the raw IDs and put them in an array like so:

```
var ids = [];

//For each element that matches ".ct input[type=checkbox]:checked".
$.each($('.ct input[type=checkbox]:checked'), function() {
    //Find the image element, get the id value, and strip the first 12 characters.
    var id = $(this).find('img').attr('id').substring(12);
    //Put ID in array.
    ids.push(id);
});
```

Comment: wht strip the first 12 characters ? I want 559429bc0d559162552c9728 id

Comment: Thought you wanted previewImagec9728. You should've specified that in your post. If you want that ID, you want: `var id = $(this).attr('id');`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/):

```
var yourIds = $(".ct input[type=checkbox]:checked").map(function(){
  return $(this).parent().attr('id');
});
```

Comment: I am getting the right values but are surrounder by brackets. ["55943ad90d559162552c9737", "55943ae70d559162552c973a"] can we have it like a list of strings ? without the brackets ?

Comment: @PSDebugger you are getting an array [i.e. an ordered list of strings] ^^. You may want to do `yourIds.join(' ')`, but you should be clearer on the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Try jquery's each:

```
$('.ct').each(function() {
   var id = $(this);
})
```

Comment: Please consider adding at least some words explaining to the OP and to further readers of you answer why and how it does reply to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

use `:has` and `.map`

```
$('.ct:has(:checked)').toArray().map(function(element, index) { return element.id })
```

or

```
$('.ct:has(:checked)').map(function(index, element) { return element.id }).toArray()
```

in both cases `.toArray()` is to get a normal array instead of a jquery array